# Does $1+M$ generate the ring $R/M$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-explanation, modules

I came across this problem in another problem. It made sense when I did it in my head, but I got stuck when I tried to write it down.

So I looked up the proof by Martin Isaac in his book (page 178) Algebra.

> **Statement:** Let $U$ be a right $R$ module and $X \subset U$ be any subset, then every maximal right (resp left) ideal of $R$ has the form $\operatorname{ann}{x}$ for some non-zero element $x$ of some simple right module $U.$

In other words, if $X$ is a simple submodule of $U$, then $\operatorname{ann}{X} = J$ where $J$ is some maximal right module of $R$. By the multiplication map $r \to xr$ and the correspondence theorem, we know $X = R/m$ and so it is implied that $\operatorname{ann}{X} = m.$

Here where I got a little confused, $\operatorname{ann}(X) = \{r \in R: rX = 0\} = \{r : rR/m=0\} = \{r :r(s + m) = m, s\in R \} = \{r: rs \in m \}$ Now since $R$ isn't assumed commutative, how do we know $r \in m$?

The author's proof goes like this, let $M$ be a maximal right ideal of $R$ and write $U = R^*/M$. So that if $U$ is a simple right module, let $x = M + 1 \in R/M$. Then $r \in \operatorname{ann}{x} \iff (M+1)r = M \iff r \in M $

Here I believe the author denotes $R^*$ as a module $R_R.$

So my question is, why exactly are we allowed to choose $M + 1$ over a generic element like $M+ r$? Is it supposed because $M + 1$ generated the quotient ring? This can't be true in every case right?

Comment: there seem to be a number of confusions in your post. first, the "statement" as you've transcribed it does not make much sense; neither the specific choice of module $U$ nor the subset $X$ seems to be used at all. the correct statement is the latter half of the sentence you've transcribed: "Every maximal right ideal of $R$ has the form $\operatorname{ann} x$ for some non-zero element $x$ of some simple right $R$-module $U$."

Comment: second, in the latter half of your post, you seem to be thinking about the annihilator of a *module* rather than the annihilator of a single element of a module. these two are distinctly different if the ring is not commutative, for reasons similar to those you write. note that, in the fact statement, the author is talking about the annihilator of an *element* rather than of a module

Comment: finally, you ask "why are we allowed to choose $M+1$ over a generic element like $M+r$?". well, look at the fact statement; in order to prove it, you just need to find a single simple right $R$-module $U$ and a *single* element $x\in U$ such that $M=\operatorname{ann} x$. so, you can take whichever choice of $x$ you want; in particular, you can take $U=R\big/M$ and $M+1\in U$.

Comment: oh also, to answer your title question; if $M$ is a two-sided ideal, then in general $1+M$ does *not* generate $R\big/M$ *as a ring*. indeed, the subring of $R\big/M$ generated by $1+M$ is the collection $$\{0+M,1+M,1+1+M,1+1+1+M,\dots\}.$$ restricting again to the case when $M$ is only a right ideal, when we say that $M+1$ generates $R\big/M$ we mean that it generates it *as an $R$-module*, not as a ring. (and if $M$ is not two-sided then $R\big/M$ will not even be a ring, in general.)

Comment: Okay so the set generated by $1 + M$ as a ring, i.e. $\left < 1 + M \right >$ is by addition and if $M$ is a one-sided right ideal, $R/M = \left 1 + M \right >$ = \{r(1 + M)\}$ as a module.